# Ansible - Could not print value of custom fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

This is a playbook part of a role that talks with vmware.
I'm is trying to set a custom fact **(target_vm)** that receive the virtual machine name.
But when I Print it's value with the debug module it apears to be empty.
It seams that the *set_fact* is correctly set because the debug output shows **{"ansible_facts": {"target_vm": "TESTVM"}**.
I've also made a Fail task that reveals if the target_vm fact is set or not.

This is the Playbook

```
- delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
  delegate_facts: yes
  vars:
    vc_hostname: 'vcenter.bio.local'
    vc_username: 'bio.local\ansible'
    vc_password: "{{ v_pass }}"
    vm_uuid: '4217200F-46D2-C9FD-E7FD-768D21B327E8' | lower
  block:
    - name: Gather only registered virtual machines
      vmware_vm_info:
        hostname: '{{ vc_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ vc_username }}'
        password: '{{ vc_password }}'
        validate_certs: False
        vm_type: vm
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: virtual_info
      no_log: true

  - name: Get VM name from UUID
    set_fact:
      target_vm: "{{ my_item.guest_name }}"
    loop: "{{ virtual_info.virtual_machines }}"
    when: my_item.uuid == vm_uuid
    loop_control:
      loop_var: my_item
    delegate_to: localhost
    delegate_facts: True
  
  - name: Verify interface name is set
    fail:
      msg: "Could not determine target_vm name!"
    when: target_vm is not defined
  
  - name: Print Output
    debug:
      msg: "The VM name is: {{ target_vm }}"
```

This is the output

```
TASK [vmwaretaks : Get VM name from UUID] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [testvm] => (item={'guest_name': 'TESTVM', 'guest_fullname': 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)', 'power_state': 'poweredOn', 'ip_address': '192.168.54.32', 'mac_address': ['00:32:52:97:e9:c8'], 'uuid': '4217200f-46d2-c9fd-e7fd-768d21b327e8', 'vm_network': {'00:32:52:97:e9:c8': {'ipv4': ['192.168.54.32'], 'ipv6': ['fe80::250:56ff:fe97:d4c3']}}, 'esxi_hostname': 'b3j15esx05.bio.local', 'cluster': 'JAS-Lab-DEP', 'attributes': {}, 'tags': []}) => {"ansible_facts": {"target_vm": "TESTVM"}, "ansible_loop_var": "my_item", "changed": false, "my_item": {"attributes": {}, "cluster": "JAS-Lab-DEP", "esxi_hostname": "b3j15esx05.bio.local", "guest_fullname": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)", "guest_name": "TESTVM", "ip_address": "192.168.54.32", "mac_address": ["00:32:52:97:e9:c8"], "power_state": "poweredOn", "tags": [], "uuid": "4217200f-46d2-c9fd-e7fd-768d21b327e8", "vm_network": {"00:32:52:97:e9:c8": {"ipv4": ["192.168.54.32"], "ipv6": ["fe80::250:56ff:fe97:d4c3"]}}}}

TASK [vmwaretaks : Verify interface name is set] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [testvm]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not determine target_vm name!"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
testvm              : ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `delegate_facts: True` on the `set_fact` task, so you are setting the variable for localhost. You are then attempting to access it in the context of the play host, which does not have it set.

You have to decide where you want to set it. If localhost is correct, you need to access it via hostvars (`hostvars['localhost']['testvm']`); if it's not, you need to remove `delegate_facts`.

Comment: You're wright @flowerysong. I was accessing the wrong way to the target_vm fact. The hostvars way makes the point. Thanks you for instruct me!